# Why can't I import apache.thrift to an IntelliJ project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, thrift

New to big Java projects so I'm not too sure how dependencies work in code. If I wanted to use apache thrift, why can I not just put

```
import org.apache.thrift.server.TServer;

import org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer;

import org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket;

import org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerTransport;
```

at the top of my files? Does this require me to download something and add it to my classpath? Wouldn't that imply that anyone else trying to run my code would also need to install it locally? I'm hoping to have standalone Java files without using something like Maven or npm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use any dependency management tool?  (Maven or Gradle?)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a dependency management tool like
[`Maven`](https://maven.apache.org/) or [`Gradle`](https://gradle.org/).

Those tools will help you with your dependencies and not only (Builds, lifecycles, etc).

So what you will have to do is the following:

For `Maven` at your `pom` file, get the dependency from the [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.thrift/libthrift/0.15.0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
    <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
    <version>0.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For `Gradle` at your `.gradle` file, again from [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.thrift/libthrift/0.15.0):

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.thrift', name: 'libthrift', version: '0.15.0'
```

If you won't use the above tools, then you must find and download the .jar file
of the library, you want to use and add it to your project's classpath.

Go to the `Apache Thrift` [website](https://thrift.apache.org/download) and there you can get the latest release.

But, to answer your question, *YES* they should also download the libraries you used unless you pack them all together (as `Maven` does it for you).

But the issue is if the other users download a different version than the one you used. Then maybe your app won't run as expected or even throw exceptions.